# How to get the download url of the artifact in Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm developing a plugin in Visual Studio Code that allows downloading of artifacts from VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) but I don't know where to get the URL? How can I get the URL of the download button?

[image: Click this image link for screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

You can get the download URL for build artifacts through [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#get-build-artifacts).

Use the REST API to get build artifacts:

```
GET https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildID}/artifacts?api-version=2.0
```

You will get the response as below:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": 270,
            "name": "drop",
            "resource": {
                "type": "Container",
                "data": "#/514582/drop",
                "properties": {
                    "localpath": "D:\\Agent\\newTFSPCagent\\_work\\3\\a"
                },
                "url": "https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/f7855e29-6f8d-429d-8c9b-41fd4d7e70a4/_apis/build/builds/1581/artifacts?artifactName=drop",
                "downloadUrl": "https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/f7855e29-6f8d-429d-8c9b-41fd4d7e70a4/_apis/build/builds/1581/artifacts?artifactName=drop&%24format=zip"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For the value of **`downloadUrl`** (as `https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/f7855e29-6f8d-429d-8c9b-41fd4d7e70a4/_apis/build/builds/1581/artifacts?artifactName=drop&%24format=zip` in above example) is what you need.

Comment: Works a treat. Thank you.