# Download TFS build artifact using api returns 401 Authorized error

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to download the TFS build artifact using REST API through a Powershell script. I'm getting a 401 Authorized error. Is there anything I'm missing?

```
invoke-webrequest -uri "https://collectionurl/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/build/builds/33002/artifacts?artifactName=drop&api-version=2.0&%24format=zip" -OutFile "C:\Temp\drop.zip" -UseDefaultCredentials
```

Tried through the browser as well, keeps giving credential pop-up. I verified my account access, all seems to be perfect.

I'm having on-premise TFS 2018.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API in question looks good, seems it just call the download url of entire drop folder. Just like this ticket: [How to get the download url of the artifact in Visual Studio Team Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46519049/how-to-get-the-download-url-of-the-artifact-in-visual-studio-team-services)

According to your description, even through the browser it still keeps giving credential pop-up.

If so, your issue may related credential cache. Try to clear any TFS credential cache stored in **Control Pane--Credential Manager**.

Besides, instead of using account/password, you could also try to use **PAT**. Username should be blank. PAT is the password.

Since you are using PAT with on-premise TFS server, check if you already *turned off Basic Authentication*.

> We recommend you keep IIS Basic Authentication turned off at all times
>   when using Azure DevOps Server. Only if necessary should you enable
>   IIS Basic Authentication. When IIS Basic Authentication is enabled on
>   your windows machine, it prevents you from using personal access
>   tokens (PATs) as an authentication mechanism.
>
> [Source link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/iis-basic-auth?view=azure-devops).

About more details for how to use powershell to download build artifacts, you could also take a look at this blog-- [Downloading Build Artifacts in TFS Build](https://blog.ehn.nu/2016/01/downloading-build-artifacts-in-tfs-build-vnext/)

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach to download the artifact. However if someone is able to find a fix for the above would be appreciated.

I used below API to download artifacts (found out we could download individual files as well). Was able to retrieve Container ID via GET build details.

```
https://collectionurl/tfs/defaultcollection/_apis/resources/Containers/${containerid}?itempath=drop
```